# Promises in Promise.all() return undefined sometimes / crawler-request package nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise

Im not sure if im using promise.all wrong, or if the nodejs package I use for retrieving pdf remotly and parsing these is overwhelmed by too many requests at once.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-wave-qikvb  // here the codesandbox

I attempted to use promise.all

```
let urls = [arrayofURLS];

function pdfData() {   
    return Promise.all(
          urls.map(item => {
            this.crawlPdf(item);
          })
        )
          .then(result => {
        // handle result
          })

}
```

This is the function that uses the crawler package (called crawler-request) :

```
    crawlPdf: async function(Url) {

      return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      let response = await crawler(Url);
      resolve(response.text);
   }
```

2 out of 5 requests are usually undefined.
But sometimes everything works o.O..

Comment: That shouldn't work - you're always mapping to an array of `undefined`s. Return the created Promise instead

Comment: change "sometimes" in the title to "always" as your map function always returns undefined

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! Actually [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56696074/3) of your `crawlPdf` code was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must return promises to the all method. Right now you aren't returning anything so it looks like `Promise.all([undefined, undefined, undefined])`

Since it looks like you can use arrow functions, you can just switch your curly brackets for parens, or put it on one line and get rid of the brackets completely - these formats always return the result of the function body.

```
urls.map(item => (
  this.crawlPdf(item)
));

urls.map(item => this.crawlPdf(item));
```

Or keep it explicit

```
urls.map(item => { return this.crawlPdf(item) });
```

Comment: im returning the response , forgot to add that. .. in crawlPdf function

Comment: Do you mean you are returning the data from that function? You need to return an actual promise. `Promise.all` accepts an array of promises, not an array of data. the `crawlPdf` function should look something like: `function () { return new Promise(...) }`

Comment: Adjusted the function ... this is how it actually looks

Comment: That looks great, but then you have to return that promise from your map callback like I explained above. You need both returns

Comment: i dont understand ... my original code already returning the promise if the  response = await crawler(Url);   actually gives a response ...

Comment: ok I replicated the code on codesandbox , this should be clear now .. hope you can help https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-wave-qikvb

Comment: sometimes im getting this error (node:369) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: idk maybe my internet connection was lagging or smth ... but on my machine i got the error plenty of times